# MongoDB : How can I get the last item from my database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, find, distinct, messaging

I've created a messaging application (like messenger), and in the main page of it, I have to display all the discussions in which the user has participated (sent or received a message).

To get users to communicate, I create rooms.

To save a message in my mongoDB database, I need to know: the room, the content of the message, the sender's id, the recipient's id, and the date of the message.

```
const message = mongoose.Schema({room: {type: String, required: true}, contenu: { type: String, required: true }, idSend: { type: Number, required: true }, idRecv: { type: Number, required: true }, date: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now }});
```

When I receive a `POST` request to my path `"/messagerie/home"`, I return all the user's rooms in the response with only the last message from each one.

For that, I use the `.find()` method.

```
Message.find({
idSend: req.body.userId,
$or: [{ idRecv: req.body.userId }]}).then(messagesAcc => res.send(messagesAcc)).catch(error => res.status(400));
```

My goal is therefore to filter all these messages there, and to send only the last messages from each room.

Comment: Do you have any indexes built in MongoDB?  It sounds like you want to group rooms by user and room, sort them by date in descending order, and lastly take the first result of each group

Comment: In MongoDB I've only a database for Users and one for Messages. How can I group by user and room please ? Cause in each message, I've the room, content, idSendUser, idRecvUser and date.